# Cross referencing tables in a mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables. One is a table of users with a unique id field, and the other is a table of data, with a column that holds the user id of whoever generated that piece of data.

I want to do something like `SELECT data,genned_by FROM datatable;`   but I want to replace the results for `genned_by` with `SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = genned_by`

So that the results from the query changes the userid into a username that corresponds with the other table.

I did some research and figured `INNER JOIN` might be what I'm looking for, but I'm left very unsure of how to use it after reading it. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT datatable.data,users.username 
FROM datatable, users
WHERE users.id = datatable.genned_by
```

Comment: "JOIN" in WHERE clause sucks!

Comment: This works. I can't believe I was overlooking an obvious solution like this. Maybe I just wanted to make it harder on myself?

Comment: Cause it's error prone. How often did you read questions here where a user forgot to add that to the WHERE clause and was wondering about wrong results. You have to learn correct syntax anyway when you need a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: @saihenjin yes it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @tombom  I was expecting you to provide me with a *real* reason (performance and such) and got a bit disappointed. If it's only a matter of self preference than for me it's way more natural and intuitive to use this syntax along with left/right joins such as: `where users.id = datatable.genned_by(+)`

Comment: @tombom "And it can be hard to read sometimes." ? are you for real ? you've just made my day... :)))

Comment: Maybe you haven't written very complicated queries yet? Also INNER JOIN syntax is ISO-conform, whereas yours is not.

Comment: @tombom Since it's good both for Oracle PLSQL as well as for MySql - it's good enough for me. Actually, I find the `INNER JOIN` syntax pretty annoying. And as for your first comment, thanks for your concerns about my experience - no need to worry I'm doing totally fine :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
SELECT d.data, u.username FROM database d INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=d.genned_by
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: :)  Thanks. This helps me understand how the INNER JOIN syntax is supposed to work now.